# Как добавить изображение в Xamarin?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

В общем... Нужно добавить изображение в Xamarin.Forms через XAML. Но есть проблема. Я уже указал несколько путей и всё тщетно. Зато в Xamarin.Forms Previewer все видно, и все показывается.

```
<Image Source="Resource/drawable/icon.png"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно вопрос: по какому пути обращаться?

Comment: Картинка точно как ресурс собирается?

Comment: Скорее всего да. учитывая, что это стартовое изображение... И задача решилась...   Source="Resource/icon.png"

Comment: напишите ответ ? ;)

Comment: Resource/icon.png

Answer (score 0):

Вам не нужно указывать полный путь до файла.
По умолчанию, система уже смотрит туда. 
Нужно указать просто:

```
Source="{icon.png}"
```